# Error "SignatureDoesNotMatch". Google Cloud Storage Bucket PUT

Tags: ruby, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url, shrine

I'm loosing my mind.

I'm using Shrine (https://github.com/janko-m/shrine) with Google Cloud Storage (https://github.com/renchap/shrine-google_cloud_storage), but when I start the `PUT` call I get this:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>
<StringToSign>
PUT
image/jpeg
1518399402
/mybucket.appspot.com/7d5e4aad1e3a737fb8d2c59571fdb980.jpg
</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

I followed this info (http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/classes/Shrine/Plugins/PresignEndpoint.html) for `presign_endpoint`, but still nothing:

```
class FileUploader < Shrine
  plugin :presign_endpoint, presign_options: -> (request) do
    filename     = request.params["filename"]
    extension    = File.extname(filename)
    content_type = Rack::Mime.mime_type(extension)

    {
      content_type: content_type
    }
  end
end
```

**I tried with and without this** (restarting the Rails server everytime).

Where am I wrong?

I also tried with Postman with a PUT to that URL and withtout any **content-type**. But still nothing.

I read here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1976 and here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1695

How can I try without Rails?

Is there a REPL (or similar) to try with my credentials and with a file?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options for just uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage as you can see in [the official docs here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#upload).

For example if you want to use Ruby Client Library, you can use this code:

```
# project_id        = "Your Google Cloud project ID"
# your-bucket-name       = "Your Google Cloud Storage bucket name"
# local_file_path   = "Path to local file to upload"
# storage_file_path = "Path to store the file in Google Cloud Storage"

require "google/cloud/storage"

storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new(project: "your-project_id")
bucket  = storage.bucket "your-bucket-name"

file = bucket.create_file "local_file_path", "storage_file_path"

puts "Uploaded #{file.name}"
```

You will need to:

> Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key.

as you can see in the [Cloud Storage Client Libraries docs here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-ruby).

However, it looks like the github repo you are using makes use of [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). If you need to create a signed URL you have [the instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program). It exists already [the `signed_urls` method for Ruby](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-storage/v1.9.0/google/cloud/storage/file?method=signed_url-instance) in the [official repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-storage).

Anyway, the error you were getting is because there was something wrong being made with the signed urls. And precisely there was a commit to the repo you were referencing (https://github.com/renchap/shrine-google_cloud_storage) 7 days ago with the name  [Fix presigned uploads](https://github.com/renchap/shrine-google_cloud_storage/commit/023e7a2be53aa6e343fc7bdf5019626ac53d448e). It looks like this commit should fix the "PUT" upload (before a "GET" was being signed, therefore it wouldn't work). Still I didn't try it so I don't know if it is actually working.

Comment: That fix was following my question.